# Use elastica with PagerFanta and dynamic querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle, pagerfanta

I have an application with symfony2 / doctrine 2 / elastica / fosElasticaBundle / pagerFanta.

I want to use a custom and dynamic queryBuilder in combination with pagerfanta and elastica. Not to transform the results but to prefilter them.

So far I was able to :
1. Use pagerfanta by itself with my custom queryBuilder :

```
    $page = $request->get('page', 1);
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $querybuilder = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Recipe')->findByTopCategoryQueryBuilder($category);
    $explorerManager = $this->get('explorer_manager');
    $pagerFanta = $explorerManager->getPagerFanta($querybuilder, $page, 4);
    $recipes = $pagerFanta->getCurrentPageResults();
```

2. Use Elastica with Pagerfanta but without my custom QueryBuilder :

   ```
   $page = $request->get('page', 1);
   $search = $request->get('search');
   $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.recipe');
   $pagerFanta = $finder->findPaginated($search);
   $recipes = $pagerFanta->getCurrentPageResults();
   ```

Now, how can I also use my custom QueryBuilder ? I know you can set a custom one in elastica config but mine has to be dynamic = take an argument, so I'd like to set it in the controller. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass custom Elastica\Query to `findPaginated`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Finder/PaginatedFinderInterface.php#L14) method:

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query::create(new \Elastica\Query\Term(array(
    'name' => $request->get('search')
));
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.recipe');
$pagerFanta = $finder->findPaginated($query);
$recipes = $pagerFanta->getCurrentPageResults();
```

Maybe code is more clear and you can see how it works when you use just [PagerFanta with ElasticaAdapter](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta#elasticaadapter) without FOSElasticaBundle:

```
// Searchable can be any valid searchable Elastica object. For example a Type or Index
$finder = new \Elastica\Index($elasticaClient, 'website.recipe');
// A Query can be any valid Elastica query (json, array, Query object)
$query = new \Elastica\Query::create(new \Elastica\Query\Term(array(
    'name' => $request->get('search')
));

$elasticaAdapter = new \Pagerfanta\Adapter\ElasticaAdapter($finder, $query);
$paginator = new \Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta($elasticaAdapter);
$results = $paginator
                ->setMaxPerPage($limit)
                ->setCurrentPage($page)
                ->getCurrentPageResults();
```

Comment: hmmm, I understand you use pagerfanta to paginate an elastica query. but my question is about using a custom doctrine queryBuilder in association with those two. is that even possible ?

Comment: I don't think so. But QueryBuilder and Elastica\Query are similar abstractions. QueryBuilder is used for Doctrine (SQL query), Elastica\Query is for ElasticSearch (JSON query). AFAIK ElasticSearch does not support SQL queries.